# Android how to create menu like this menudrawer

Tags: android, menu

Can anyone help me to create menu like this menu 
you can see it over the main activity just slide from right

[image: Menu]

Comment: http://av.victorhaggqvist.com/2012/10/androiddrawer/index.html

Comment: If you keep deleting questions that have answers there is no reason for them to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) with a semi-transparent background and some fancy styling!

You can create one like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The drawer -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: other question how to put arrow in the centered right for Drawer ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. If you mean that "Play Next" button, then it's just an ImageButton with a centered gravity within the @+id/drawer layout